# ionic 1 fileuri to blob not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am taking the image link as POST Method and I want to convert the image link as BLOB and store it on local storage for offline work.

```
    function convertFileToDataURLviaFileReader(url, callback){
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.onload = function() {
        var reader  = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
          callback(reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.send();
    }
```

I called the method as follows -

```
    convertFileToDataURLviaFileReader($rootScope.currentUser.profile,function(base64Data){
window.localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_IMAGE_KEY, base64Data);
                });
```

I am using this method but its not working. Would someone let me know the the problem and provide me solution for this?

Comment: don't use LocalStorage or base64, use blobs and indexedDB. You are not suppose to save large data in a simple key/value lookup